# Valores foraneos en Formularios

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo 3 tablas.

Plantas:

```
Schema::create('plantas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre'); // Nombre de la planta.
            $table->string('tamaño'); // Clasifica segun si es arbol, arbusto o hierba. 
            $table->string('flor'); // Si tiene o no flor.
            $table->string('hoja'); // Si es de hoja caduca o perenne.
            $table->text('descripcion'); // Caracteristicas del vegetal.
            $table->string('foto')->nullable(); // Esta variable sera utilizada para almacenar fotos. Es opcional.
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

User:

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Y Comentarios:

```
Schema::create('comentarios', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('miembro'); // Primero creas la variable. Luego creas la relación foranea.
            $table->foreign('miembro')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->unsignedInteger('planta'); // Primero creas la variable. Luego creas la relación foranea.
            $table->foreign('planta')->references('id')->on('plantas');
            $table->text('comentario');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comentario tiene claves foraneas que apuntan a User y plantas.
En relación a esto, tengo una vista que muestra la lista de comentarios para una determinada planta e incluye un formulario con el que un usuario identificado puede crear un comentario para esa planta:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <h2 class="text-center text-mute"> {{ __("Comentarios acerca del :nombre", ['nombre' => $plantas->nombre]) }} </h2>
        @forelse($comentario as $c)
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading panel-heading-forum">
                <h3>
                    Escrito por {{$c->usuario->name}}
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                {{ $c->comentario }}
            </div>
        </div>
        @empty
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ __("No hay ningún comentario sobre plantas en este momento") }}
        </div>
        @endforelse
        <a href="/flora/public" class="btn btn-info pull-right"> {{ __("Volver a la lista de plantas") }} </a><br>


    @Logged()
        @include('partials.errors')
        <form method="POST" action="../comentario"> {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="comentario" class="col-md-12 control-label"> {{ __("Escribe un comentario...") }}
            </label>
            <input id="comentario" class="form-control" name="comentario" value="{{ old('comentario') }}"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="addComentario" class="btn btn-default"> {{ __("Añadir Comentario") }}
        </button>
    </form>
    @else
        <p>Tienes que iniciar sesión si quieres escribir comentarios</p>
    @endLogged


    @include('partials.errors') </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

La función store() de ComentarioController.php es la encargada de su manejo.
web.php:

```
Route::post('/comentario', 'ComentarioController@store');
```

ComentarioController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Comentario;
use App\plantas;
use App\Http\Requests\ComentarioRequest;

class ComentarioController extends Controller{
    public function store(ComentarioRequest $comentario_request){
        $comentario_request->merge(['miembro' => auth()->id()]);
        Comentario::create($comentario_request->input());
        return back()->with('message', ['success', __('Comentario creado correctamente')]);
    }
}
```

Durante esta se convoca a un fichero llamado ComentarioRequest.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ComentarioRequest extends FormRequest{
    public function authorize(){
        return auth()->check();
    }

    public function rules(){
        return [
            'comentario' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

Pero ahora, en el fichero ComentarioController.php tenemos
**$comentario_request->merge(['miembro' => auth()->id()]);**

Esta linea de codigo sirve para pasarle el valor foraneo del usuario, pero ahora tambien necesito pasarle el valor foraneo de la planta. ¿Alguien sabe como?

Por cierto, probe a incluir

**$comentario_request->merge(['planta' => auth()->id()]);**

Esto probocara que pueda introducir el comentario, pero se dirigira a la planta con el mismo id que el usuario en lugar de la planta para la cual se haga el comentario.

Y cierto, el enlace en web.php para ir a los comentarios de cada planta es el siguiente:

```
Route::get('/comentarios/{plantas}', 'PlantasController@show');
```

Comment: ¿por qué usas merge? ¿no sería más fácil usar simplemente push? Realmente no entiendo para que le agregas información al request, lo que estás intentando hacer creo que es asociar modelos basados en sus relaciones. En teoría los valores que necesitas (el usuario y la planta) ya debes tenerlos, deberías poder obtenerlos de alguna relación.

Comment: @Shaz lo de ComentarioRequest son normas, como que no te dejes un campo vacio o que no supere una longitud, es opcional pero en fin... Lo de merge es lo que me encontre en mi documentación. En esta habia otro modo que era irme al fichero Comentario.php y usar un metodo llamado boot(), pero lo encontre más complejo.

Comment: Creo que no entendiste mi comentario... en fin.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he soludionado.
De entrada, resultaba que podia usar en el formulario este codigo:

```
<input type="hidden" name="planta" value="{{ $plantas->id }}"/>
```

Con esto justo despues del ***{{ csrf_field() }}*** puedo recuperar el id de las plantas y usarlo como variable para mi formulario.

Una vez lo he obtenido, como seguridad ire a ComentarioRequest.php y editare las reglas para hacerlo obligatorio:

```
public function rules(){
        return [
            'planta' => 'required|exists:plantas,id',
            'comentario' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

Y con esto ya se deberia poder ejecutar el formulario.